WPF MVVM binding DataGrid to an IEnumerable causes binding errors to Int32
I'm writing a simple WPF interface to retrieve SwiftMessages using a library component. I cannot change the component. I have a DataGrid that should show the messages, one message per row.
My only use of code-behind is to instantiate the DataContext (so yes dear MVVM absolutionists, it's not 100% MVVM, but please be nice and useful as I'm learning):
public SwiftSearchWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new UI.ViewModels.SwiftSearchViewModel();
}

The relevant XAML is thus:
<DataGrid Name="gridMessages" ItemsSource="{Binding SwiftMessages}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Message Type"  Binding="{Binding MessageType, Mode=OneWay}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Message Length" Binding="{Binding MessageLength, Mode=OneWay}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Counter Party"  Binding="{Binding CounterParty, Mode=OneWay}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Direction"  Binding="{Binding Direction, Mode=OneWay}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Message Date"  Binding="{Binding MessageDate, Mode=OneWay}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Network Interface Message Reference" Binding="{Binding NetworkInterfaceMessageReference, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Own Bic" Binding="{Binding OwnBic, Mode=OneWay}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

On my instance of SwiftSearchViewModel is a property:
public SwiftMessages SwiftMessages
{
    get
    {
        if (_query == null) return null;
        return _query?.Messages;
    }
}

Relevant parts of SwiftMessages are:
    public class SwiftMessages : IEnumerable, IEnumerator
    {
        private List<SwiftMessage> _items;

        #region IEnumerable, IEnumerator
        private int _position;

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this;
        }

        public object Current
        {
            get
            {
                return _position;
            }
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            if (_position < _items.Count)
            {
                _position++;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            _position = -1;
        }
        #endregion
    }


...and relevant parts of SwiftMessage are below. I've omitted some of the properties, but they're all strings, except for MessageLength:
    public class SwiftMessage
    {
        public int MessageLength
        {
            get { return _messageLength; }
            set { _messageLength = value; }
        }


        public string MessageType
        {
            get { return _messageType; }
            set { _messageType = value; }
        }
    }

Two messages are retrieved and I get two rows shown in the DataGrid. However, the individual cell values do not bind. I get these errors:
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'MessageType' property not found on 'object' ''Int32' (HashCode=1)'. BindingExpression:Path=MessageType; DataItem='Int32' (HashCode=1); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'MessageLength' property not found on 'object' ''Int32' (HashCode=1)'. BindingExpression:Path=MessageLength; DataItem='Int32' (HashCode=1); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'CounterParty' property not found on 'object' ''Int32' (HashCode=1)'. BindingExpression:Path=CounterParty; DataItem='Int32' (HashCode=1); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Direction' property not found on 'object' ''Int32' (HashCode=1)'. BindingExpression:Path=Direction; DataItem='Int32' (HashCode=1); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'MessageDate' property not found on 'object' ''Int32' (HashCode=1)'. BindingExpression:Path=MessageDate; DataItem='Int32' (HashCode=1); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'NetworkInterfaceMessageReference' property not found on 'object' ''Int32' (HashCode=1)'. BindingExpression:Path=NetworkInterfaceMessageReference; DataItem='Int32' (HashCode=1); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'OwnBic' property not found on 'object' ''Int32' (HashCode=1)'. BindingExpression:Path=OwnBic; DataItem='Int32' (HashCode=1); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'MessageType' property not found on 'object' ''Int32' (HashCode=2)'. BindingExpression:Path=MessageType; DataItem='Int32' (HashCode=2); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'MessageLength' property not found on 'object' ''Int32' (HashCode=2)'. BindingExpression:Path=MessageLength; DataItem='Int32' (HashCode=2); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'CounterParty' property not found on 'object' ''Int32' (HashCode=2)'. BindingExpression:Path=CounterParty; DataItem='Int32' (HashCode=2); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Direction' property not found on 'object' ''Int32' (HashCode=2)'. BindingExpression:Path=Direction; DataItem='Int32' (HashCode=2); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'MessageDate' property not found on 'object' ''Int32' (HashCode=2)'. BindingExpression:Path=MessageDate; DataItem='Int32' (HashCode=2); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'NetworkInterfaceMessageReference' property not found on 'object' ''Int32' (HashCode=2)'. BindingExpression:Path=NetworkInterfaceMessageReference; DataItem='Int32' (HashCode=2); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'OwnBic' property not found on 'object' ''Int32' (HashCode=2)'. BindingExpression:Path=OwnBic; DataItem='Int32' (HashCode=2); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

My questions are:

What Int32 is it trying to bind to?
I'm aware that I'm simply using an IEnumerable from a C# library and trying to bind to it. I consider the data generated by the library to be my Model. I've seen other examples where the model constructs ObservableCollections etc (not possible in this case) to feed the UI, but surely that breaks the concept that the Model should work independantly of the UI.
How do I fix this so that the properties show?
Lastly, I have a few other properties of SwiftMessage that are string[]. I'd like to concatenate the array into a single CSV string and show that in a cell. How do I slot this calculation inbetween the XAML and the model data?


"What Int32 is it trying to bind to?" - how are we supposed to tell that without seeing the implementation of your SwiftMessages class? Apparently it implements an IEnumerable of Int32 objects. Why would you implement a custom collection type in the first place?

@Clemens - it's IEnumerable, so presumably part of that interface which is how binding would iterate through the data. I don't know how binding works under the bonnet but I was hoping that folks here do and would be able to indicate how binding goes about acquiring data for a DataGrid. The class is about 500 lines and I can't post most of it because I work for a bank. I'll add the part that relates to the interfaces.

Post the relevant parts. How exactly does the class implement IEnumerable? There is obviously something wrong with it.

Returning _position form Current is wrong. It must be return _items[_position];

@Clemens - that will be why. Thank you.

MoveNext() is also wrong. It must not return true when _position == _items.Count. And there must be private int _position = -1;. It is a terrible idea to implement this yourself.

Take a look at this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext?view=net-8.0#examples

Thanks @Clemens. Have modified. Interesting that it's calling properties that aren't listed in the binding (causing a couple of other problems). Any idea how I might manage the 4'th item.

You haven't set AutoGenerateColumns to false.

Ah, thank you. I now have two messages being shown.

"My only use of code-behind is to instantiate the DataContext (so yes dear MVVM absolutionists, it's not 100% MVVM, but please be nice and useful as I'm learning)" - Usually you add plenty of code to a C# aka code-behind file. Event handlers and other complex UI logic that brings to the view and can't be implemented using XAML. While XAML is preferable in terms of defining the layout using C# in the view is not a violation of MVVM. All controls are written in C#. MVVM does not care about programming languages.

That C# in the view violates MVVM is so wrong and doesn't make any sense. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to implement certain things when using MVVM as XAML is very limited.

Your type should not implement IEnumerator. The IEnumerator is provided by the IEnumerable interface. This is extremely important as you want to be able to return different IEnumerator instances for each enumeration.

@BionicCode - I heave learnt a lot here, especially your last point. Thanks v much. Will modify the code above in light of this.

I don't understand 2). Using ObservableCollection in the application model does not break MVVM. It looks like you are overcomplicating things based on a misconception?

My understanding is that the Model doesn't know/care about the View. The ViewModel takes care of transmuting the data for the View, but if I have to start recoding my Model to cater for the fact it's being used in a view (converting Lists to ObservableCollections, for example), this breaks that mould.

Please do not make significant edits after a question has been answered. Anybody coming to this topic later should still be able to understand what the original problem was.

You should avoid implementing a custom IEnumerator that you return from IEnumerable.GetEnumerator. It's safer to let the compiler generate the proper (default) implementation for you and use yield (in your case you would have avoided some stressful hours? to debug your code). You should also implement the generic IEnumerable<T> interface:
public class SwiftMessages : IEnumerable<SwiftMessage>
{
  private readonly List<SwiftMessage> _items = new List<SwiftMessage>();

  public IEnumerator<SwiftMessage> GetEnumerator() => EnumerateItems();
  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => ((IEnumerable<SwiftMessage>)this).GetEnumerator();

  private IEnumerator<SwiftMessage> EnumerateItems()
  {
    foreach (SwiftMessage item in _items)
    {
      yield return item;
    }
  }
}

In your case you can simply return the enumerator of the backing collection:
public class SwiftMessages : IEnumerable<SwiftMessage>
{
  private readonly List<SwiftMessage> _items = new List<SwiftMessage>();

  public IEnumerator<SwiftMessage> GetEnumerator() => _items.GetEnumerator();
  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => ((IEnumerable<SwiftMessage>)this).GetEnumerator();
}

This will also fix your questions 1-3. The question remains, how do you add items to SwifMessages? Instead of implementing IEnumerable<T> alone you should implement IList and INotifyCollectionChanged. This will also improve the performance in data binding sceanrios where you bind to SwiftMessages.
That being said, when creating a collection that will serve as a binding source you should always consider to extend ObservableCollection and add/override functionality (if neccessary). ObservableCollection efficiently implements IEnumerable<T>, IList<t> and INotifyCollectionChanged:
public class SwiftMessages : ObservableCollection<SwiftMessage>
{
}

In regards to question 4): you can introduce a dedicated computed property that returns the CSV formatted string.
Please note that every class that serves as a binding source must implement INotifyPropertyChanged (not implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on the binding source will cause a data binding to create a memory leak):
public class SwiftMessage : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
  private string[] values;

  public string[] Values
  {
    get => this.values;
    set
    {
      this.values = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.CsvValues));
    }
  }

  public string CsvValues => string.Join(';', this.Values);

  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    => this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SwiftMessages}">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="CSV Values"  
                        Binding="{Binding CsvValues}" /> <!-- Binding is OneWay by default -->
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

Alternatively, for example when you can't modify the data model to add a new property, you can use an IValueConverter:
class StringValuesToCsvStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
    => value is IEnumerable<string> values 
      ? string.Join(';', values)
      : Binding.DoNothing;

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
    => throw new NotSupportedException();
}

<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <StringValuesToCsvStringConverter x:Key="StringValuesToCsvStringConverter" />
  </Window.Resources>

  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SwiftMessages}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="CSV Values"  
                          Binding="{Binding Values, Converter={StaticResource StringValuesToCsvStringConverter}}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
</Window>


That's a really comprehensive answer. I'm unlikely to be allowed to make changes to the Swift assembly unless it is a bug fix (i.e. the IEnumerable issue), so it's probable that I cannot implement INotifyPropertyChanged on it.

More generally, where you've stated "not implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on the binding source will cause a data binding to create a memory leak", does this mean if I am exposing an assembly/library to binding, I need to modify that library to accommodate this (kind of breaks MVVM), or build a duplicate of the classes within the ViewModel that implement this interface? I'd much rather just be able to directly expose code from existing libraries than have to partially clone them for MVVM.

What you can do is to create a new data model and copy the data to it. And after editing the new model in the UI you copy it back and update the model. This is also common practice if data models used in the application model have to be exposed to the view by the view model. If you must use the existing classes then you should open a bug ticket as those memory leaks are actually bugs in your source code that have to be addressed and fixed.

So I understand this better, how does the memory leak occur?

If the binding is configured to OneTime or OneWayToSource there won't be a memory leak. In every other case the binding engine will have to track property changes. If the object does not implement proprrties as dependency properties or does not implement INotifyPropertyCganged then the binding engine uses reflection to register a property changed handler. It does this by adding the source object to a static table which will convert the object to a GC to: the garbage collector will not be able to collect the object and all references of this object to free memory. That's the point.

So, since you can't change the model classes, you have to wrap them into a data model class that the view model can expose for data binding. It report a bug. I personally would not recommend to tweak model classes to be directly used in the view model (or view). I would wrap/copy the data to new data models that are dedicated to data binding (as they implement this interface and additional properties that might be useful in the context of the view for example a ISelected property. You usually don't want to have such properties in you model classes.
